# Should I remove a question that started upset emotions?

Tags: discussion

Unintentionally, I started a very infected thread and now I'm not sure if I should remove it or let it be. I don't want the useful commenters to loose reputation but I feel that most of the contents is less than useful (people defending their own friends, over-suspicious interpretations - including my own, sadly, annoyance etc.)

*I'm not giving a link to the original discussion because I'm scared waste-less to start yet another flame. Sorry.*

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, it is not possible for an OP to delete a question with upvoted answers (partly for the reason you surmise- that answerers would lose reputation)

Comment: Unless you're mistaken, that answers my question.    :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible for you to delete your question, since it's not possible for an OP to delete a question that has either

1. At least one answer with upvotes
2. More than one answer

This is partly for the reason you surmise- that answerers would lose reputation for the deleted question. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) for more detailed information.

It is technically possible for a moderator to close and delete the question, but in this case it's unlikely they'd do so (both because of the upvoted answers and because it's not, in my opinion, an unusually emotional discussion for Meta). However, if you are of the opinion that the comments have devolved into an unconstructive discussion, you *should* flag the comments to that effect, and a moderator might delete some or all of the *comments* (not the post itself) if they agree.

Comment: Strange, though. I just remembered that in my rep log it says sometimes "-xx, deleted".

Comment: Those are probably cases that were deleted either by a moderator or by multiple high-rep users.

Comment: @DavidRobinson Apologies first i know this isn't right place to ask but i couldn't find a way to contact you. I read your articel http://stackoverflow.blog/2017/01/Developers-without-Borders-The-Global-Stack-Overflow-Network/?cb=1. I just wanted to know that how much contribution is from Pakistan because i am from Pakistan and i almost visit daily stackoverflow and my main focus is answering the questions. So please could you provide some details or update the article if possible.?